# How to show that adjoint operator is a linear operator and its norm is equal to that of the original operator?

Tags: matrices

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint

Adjoint operator defintion is:
[image]

1. How to show that adjoint operator is a linear operator?
2. Its norm is equal to that of the original operator?
   The norm is defined as:
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $H^*=\{U\in L(H,\mathbb{C})|U$ is continuous$\}$. The Riesz representation theorem says that if $U\in H^*$, then there is a sole $y\in H$ s.t. for every $x$, $U(x)=<x,y>$. Since $|<Ax,y>|\leq ||x||||A||||y||$, $x\rightarrow <Ax,y>\in H^*$ and there is a sole $A^*y\in H$ s.t. $<Ax,y>=<x,A^*y>$. Now $A^*\in L(H)$ because $<Ax,y_1+ay_2>=<Ax,y_1>+\overline{a}<Ax,y_2>=<x,A^*y_1>+<x,aA^*y_2>=\cdots$.

EDIT. Let $M=\sup_{||x||=||y||=1}|<Ax,y>|$. With $y=Ax/||Ax||$, we obtain $||Ax||\leq M$ and then $||A||\leq M$. On the other hand, $|<Ax,y>|\leq ||A||$ and $M\leq ||A||$ and finally $||A||=M$. Also $M=\sup_{||x||=||y||=1}|<A^*y,x>|$ and $M=||A^*||$, that implies $||A||=||A^*||$.

Moreover $(A^*)^*=A$ and $0\leq ||A||^2=\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||^2=\sup_{||x||=1}<Ax,Ax>=\sup_{||x||=1}<x,A^*Ax>=||A^*A||$.
In the same way 
$||A^*||^2=\sup_{||x||=1}<x,AA^*x>=||AA^*||$. We deduce that $||A||^2=||AA^*||=||A^*A||$.

EDIT. The considered question was put "on hold". I think that the "clumsy" students are unwelcome on MSE and also on MO. On some forums, we see more and more complaints from students in that direction.I think our job is to "educate" them and give them good habits. I vote for reopening.